# Facebook PHP SDK upgrade v4 to v5 and OpenGraph session

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I want to upgrade FB PHP SDK to v5 but can't find any upgrade guide or so.
For now I'm using just FB login and registration through PHP SDK, but I also want to add getting data from OpenGraph `/video/{video-id}`.

In OpenGraph docs I see every endpoint requires some `$session`, but in PHP SDK I see that FacebookSession was deprecated in v5 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/5.0.0).

What do I need to change to keep my login/registration working and how do I get this session in v5? Or should I stick with v4 for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of the question is as said in @Yassine Guedidi's given link:

> From v4 to v5: https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5

The second part - to get App access token is:

```
$oFb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{app-id}',
    'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);
$access_token = $oFb->getApp()->getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 1):

From v4 to v5: https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5
From v3 to v5: https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v3-x-to-v5

By one of the contributors to the SDK :)

Comment: I will try this on Monday, but I still can't see how to make request without a token. In v4 I could get `$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);`, but in v5 I can't find how to get access token of an app.